# jquery selector help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

Im assembling a form validation script and Im pretty stuck on this:

```
$("*").live('click', function(){
    if($(".validate").val()=="")
    {
        $(this).addClass("partError");
    }
});
```

The first selector is attached to everything so that it is constantly updating, but when the function runs it won't do anything.

I want this function to only select the `input` belonging to this class that are empty. But there can be a variable number of these elements belonging to the `.validate` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you attaching it to everything?

```
$(".validate").live('click', function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).addClass("partError");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$("html").live('click', function(){
  if($(".validate").val()=="")
  {
    $(this).addClass("partError");
  }
});
```